# How to import Opencv in AWS Lambda function using compiled .so file

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, opencv, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get opencv and numpy imported into a basic python function.  I have a zipped lambda package folder with the following contents:

- lambda_function.py
- cv2/

  - cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  - __init__.py
  - __init__.pyc
  - __pycache__/

    - __init__.cpython-36.pyc
  - numpy/

    - lots of files in here

(the cv2 and numpy folders are from https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages)

the function code looks like this:

```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  import json
  import boto3
  import botocore

  def lambda_handler(event, context):
      print("testing")
```

When I run the function this is the error I get back:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)

I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here and would be grateful for any help!

Comment: i am not a developer but one of my friend had similar problems , what he did was he compiled the code on AWS EC2 Linux AMI and then deployed , since Lambda runs on that only , maybe this will help